# I want to convert tensoflow code to pytorch code, how do I do that?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

```
 encoder_input  = Input((1,125,16))
en_conv        = Conv2D(16, (1, 64), activation='elu', padding="same", 
                                kernel_constraint=max_norm(2., axis=(0, 1, 2)))(encoder_input)
        en_conv        = BatchNormalization(axis=3, epsilon=1e-05, momentum=0.1)(en_conv)
        en_conv        = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(1,125//125))(en_conv)  
        en_conv        = Conv2D(10, (1, 32), activation='elu', padding="same", 
                                kernel_constraint=max_norm(2., axis=(0, 1, 2)))(en_conv)
        en_conv        = BatchNormalization(axis=3, epsilon=1e-05, momentum=0.1)(en_conv)
        en_conv        = AveragePooling2D((1,125//125))(en_conv)
        en_conv        = Flatten()(en_conv)
        encoder_output = Dense(64, kernel_constraint=max_norm(0.5))(en_conv)
```

I would like to convert the above tensoflow model to the pytorch code form below, but I am in trouble because there are functions that are not in pytorch. How can I convert it?

```
class Conv2D_Norm_Constrained(nn.Conv2d):
    def __init__(self, max_norm_val, norm_dim, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.max_norm_val = max_norm_val
        self.norm_dim = norm_dim

    def get_constrained_weights(self, epsilon=1e-8):
        norm = self.weight.norm(2, dim=self.norm_dim, keepdim=True)
        return self.weight * (torch.clamp(norm, 0, self.max_norm_val) / (norm + epsilon))

    def forward(self, input):
        return F.conv2d(input, self.get_constrained_weights(), self.bias, self.stride, self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)


self.en_conv = nn.Sequential(
                    Conv2D_Norm_Constrained(in_channels=1, out_channels=16, kernel_size=(1, 64), padding="same", max_norm_val=2.0, norm_dim=(0, 1, 2)),
                    nn.ELU(),
                    nn.BatchNorm2d(16,eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1),
                    nn.AvgPool2d(pool_size=(1,125//125)),
                    nn.Flatten(),
                    nn.Linear(,64),
                    nn.ELU(),
                    nn.Linear(64,3)
                )
```

I would like to convert the above tensoflow model to the pytorch code form below, but I am in trouble because there are functions that are not in pytorch. How can I convert it?

Comment: Do you want the code to be converted or will it suffice to convert your model form TensorFlow to PyTorch?

Comment: I want to change the code.

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: Dense(64, kernel_constraint=max_norm(0.5)) and  BatchNormalization(axis=3, epsilon=1e-05, momentum=0.1)

Comment: How can I convert these two codes to pytorch?